# How to judge whether model is overfitting or underfitting

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation, overfitting, boosting

When validation or test data cannot be predicted properly and the model is suitable only for train data, the model is overfitting or underfitting.
When I looking for a lot of reference , it seems to be overfitting when the test loss increases as the epoch(example - number of tree) increases.
But I think that the large difference between the loss of train and test is not good.
So, if the difference between the performance index(example auc) of train and validation test is more than 0.005, I think it is overfitting or underfitting. Is this the right way to judge?

Comment: There are many queries on CV about fitting models. Browse them for good suggestions.